# Ellipsis showing as [][][] unknown unicode when text is beside Glyphicon on IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8, glyphicons

```
<a href="#" class="ellipsis tree-item no-borders" title="longnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-closed tree-icon"></span>
    longnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
</a>
```

Hi, I set the text-overflow to ellipsis but I get something like this when rendering in IE8: 
[insert icon]Name[][][] 

It works fine without the glyphicon but shows the unknown unicode when I have glyphicons. It also works fine in all other browsers.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="ellipsis tree-item no-borders" title="longnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee">
longnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
    <span class="pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-folder-closed tree-icon"></span>   
</a>
```

The solution I found was to reverse the order of the glyphicon and text, and made the glyphicon to float left.
For some reason IE8 uses the font of the first child to render ellipsis? (Need someone to verify this).